# $1 + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 5} + {1 \over 7} - {1 \over 4} + {1 \over 9} + {1 \over 11} - {1 \over 6} + +-...$ conditionally convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

$$1 + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 5} + {1 \over 7} - {1 \over 4} + {1 \over 9} + {1 \over 11} - {1 \over 6} + +-...$$

I want to show first that $S_{3n}$, $S_{3n+1}$ and $S_{3n+2}$ converges to the same limit, I show

$$S_{3n} = (1 + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 2}) + ({1 \over 5} + {1 \over 7} - {1 \over 4}) + ({1 \over 9} + {1 \over 11} - {1 \over 6}) + ... + ({1 \over 4n-3} + {1 \over 4n-1} - {1 \over 2n})$$

but how to proceed from here?

Comment: Write $(\frac1{4n-3}+\frac1{4n-1}-\frac1{2n})$ over a common denominator.

Comment: If any of the sequences $S_{3n+i}$ converges, all three converge, since the other two sequences will eventually be infinitesimally close to any of the others.

Comment: I see that $\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n-2}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n})$, so that $\lim _{n\to \infty}S=\lim _{n\to \infty} \frac{3}{2}\sum \left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$, hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1}{4n}=\frac{1}{4n-3}-\frac{1}{4n-2}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$ so $$\lim _{n\to \infty}S=\frac{3}{2}\lim _{n\to \infty}\sum _n\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$ and $$\log (x+1)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}..$$ so $$\log(2)=\log(1+1)=\sum \left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$ so $S=\frac{3}{2}\log (2)$ Hope it will help

Comment: Your intermediate steps are not very clear, esp. in the $\lim S_n$ formula there is a sum sign missing. Perhaps it would be better to write $S_n=L_{4n}+\frac12L_{2n}$ where $L_k$ are the partial sums of the alternating harmonic series.

Comment: @LutzL thank you very much, I will correct that, however I'm not familiar with alternating harmonic series, so I will leave the notation that way.

Comment: It is just $L_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac1k$, the alternating version of the divergent harmonic series, i.e., the partial sums of $\ln(1+1)$ versus the ones of $-\ln(1-1)$. You have the problem that the partial sums of the given series can not be rewritten as you did since the highest indices of the parts $L_{4n}$ and $L_{2n}$ are not the same.

Comment: @LutzL thank you very much, You are right, I noticed that the partial sums will not be the same. I will learn that content.

Comment: will you fix the answer?

Comment: @Stabilo I think LutzL means $S_{3n}\neq \frac{3}{2}\sum _n\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ however, $\lim _{n\to \infty}S_{3n}=\frac{3}{2} \lim _{n\to \infty}\sum _n\left(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}\right)$ should hold.

Answer (score 4):

The series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4n-3}+\frac1{4n-1}-\frac1{2n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{8n-3}{2n(4n-1)(4n-3)}$$

and this thing is a converging positive series, since

$$\frac{8n-3}{2n(4n-1)(4n-3)}\le\frac4{(4n-1)(4n-3)}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$|S_{3n+1}-S_{3n}| \leq \frac{1}{n}$$
$$|S_{3n+2}-S_{3n}| \leq \frac{1}{n}$$
So if $(S_{3n})$ converges, all the three converges

No to prove that $(S_{3n})$ converges, all you need to do is to write $\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n}$ over the same denominator and use a comparaison.